# What is the difference between extending a Wi-Fi and creating a new one with the same name?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powerline-networking, time-capsule, airport-express

First let me start with my Wi-Fi setup:

On my first floor I have an Apple Time Capsule connected to the net working as the DNS and DHCP and creating both a 2.4 and a 5 GHz network (with different names). On the second floor I have an Apple AirPort Express extending the 5 GHz network because the signal gets weaker. Everything kinda worked although huge downloads on the second floor did take way to long. (I tried to build something with Docker and moved back downstairs to download all the containers !)

I recently (today) received a power-line device to fix my Wi-Fi speeds: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00LPE19RI/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

After connecting the first power-line adapter to my socket I was able to connect to the second one with nearly full speed. However after connecting the AE to it, my whole Wi-Fi including my Time Capsule and the AE itself froze and didn't restore functionality until I disconnected the AE again. Tried it a few times, no success. Once my AE was both extending the Wi-Fi and connected to the LAN it completely froze all over again.

I fixed it my changing my AE to create a NEW 5 GHz Wi-Fi with the same name as the Time Capsule and suddenly it worked as intended. High speed on both floors via Wi-Fi. Hurray!

[image]

As I remember from school you can extend a Wi-Fi just by creating a new one with the same name and you're good to go. Is there a difference between extending and creating a new one with the same name? Or was this issue related to some Apple stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apple's UI, "Extend a wireless network" is specifically about having one AirPort base station product connect *wirelessly* to another AirPort base station to extend its network.

If you can use Ethernet (including via powerline Ethernet adapters) as the backhaul between two AirPort base stations, you should use "Create a network" on both base stations, and give them the same network name, security type, and password.

If you connect two base stations together via both Ethernet and wireless simultaneously, you're creating a network loop that will instantly overload and freeze the network (as you discovered).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference that I'm aware of between extending wifi, and creating a new wifi using the same SSID and authentication info, is usually extensions use a wireless "repeater" that essentially pick up on the wireless signal from an existing AP and then boost and rebroadcast it. This requires only power, and no physical connection to the network, due to the fact that it is essentially a wireless "amplifier" and will still route all your traffic through your original AP and then your routing device. When you create a new network using the same information, you have to have some type of physical connection to your network, in order to pass the traffic from the AP with your "new" wireless connection, to your routing device.